# Redirect tail command output to docker logs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a docker image which will run a command similar with tail, how can I redirect the output of this command in the logs of the container?

Comment: Anything that's on the main container process's stdout will appear in `docker logs`.  The easiest approach is usually to configure your application to write directly to stdout, instead of to a file.  Do you have a [mcve] showing a case that's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you output to stdout or stderr will be part of the docker container logs by default.

So for example while this container is running

```sh
docker run --rm --name busy busybox sh -c "while true; do echo 'to stdout'; echo 'to stderr' >&2; sleep 1; done"
```

... you can inspect its logs:

```sh
docker logs -f busy
```

So in short: Just use your `tail -f` normally.